# Is it possible to use new Observation Framework with UIKit

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

Apple released their new [Observation Framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Observation) in WWDC23 and they use it with SwiftUI. I've seen lots of resources about how to use it with SwiftUI but I cannot find anything how can I use it with UIKit. So, I am curious about is there any way to use it with UIKit.

How we can use the two together? If we cannot, Why? and What are restrictions of [Observation Framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Observation)?

Comment: I have no idea but to me it looks like `withObservationTracking(_:onChange:)` would work outside of SwiftUI

Comment: Simple Change tracker based on withObservationTracking https://gist.github.com/SmartJSONEditor/33d796e81554205fd491b6449376c426